# nokogiri-1.11.2-x86-mingw32 requires ruby version < 3.1.dev, >= 2.5, which is incompatible with the current version, ruby 2.3.3p222

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

nokogiri-1.11.2-x86-mingw32 requires ruby version < 3.1.dev, >= 2.5, which is
incompatible with the current version, ruby 2.3.3p222

Anyone know how to fix this or what it is?

Comment: did you try to update 2.3.3p222 with ruby 2.5

Comment: i dont know how

Comment: check here one ruby official page https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/

Comment: Your Ruby version is too low, you have to at least have 2.5 installed for that version of nokogiri, just like it says

Comment: Alright, thanks Zia and Rockwell

Comment: So just to be clear, you need to 1) install Ruby (at minimum) 2.5 on your computer, and then 2) set it to be the default version used by the app, likely in the gemfile.  Both of those you could google to get solutions for.

Comment: Alright @RockwellRice

Comment: Could not find gem 'puma (~> 3.7) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. (Bundler::GemNotFound) Anyone know about this error message?

Comment: try `bundle update`